# Django. Введите правильный адрес электронной почты

Tags: python-3.x, django

При регистрации пользователя через форму регистрации выскакивает ошибка "Введите правильный адрес электронной почты". В админке всё работает без проблем.

Модель:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from time import timezone
from django.db import models

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin

from django.core.validators import MaxLengthValidator
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class TemporaryBanIp(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'TemporaryBanIps'

    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField("IP адрес")
    attempts = models.IntegerField("Неудачных попыток", default=0)
    time_unblock = models.DateTimeField("Время разблокировки", blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField("Статус блокировки", default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ip_address


class TemporaryBanIpAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('ip_address', 'status', 'attempts', 'time_unblock')
    search_fields = ('ip_address',)


class AuthUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, phone_number,
                    firstname, lastname, patronymic, birth_day,
                    org_name, org_address,
                    passport_s, passport_n, inn_id, password=None):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=email, # AuthUserManager.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            phone_number=phone_number,
            firstname=firstname,
            lastname=lastname,
            patronymic=patronymic,
            birth_day=birth_day,
            org_name=org_name,
            org_address=org_address,
            passport_s=passport_s,
            passport_n=passport_n,
            inn_id=inn_id
        )

        user.is_admin = False
        # user.is_staff = False
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, **kwargs):
        user = self.create_user(**kwargs)

        user.is_admin = True
        # user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


class AuthUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'AuthUsers'
        verbose_name = 'поле (пользователь)'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Пользователи'

    username = models.CharField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(8)], max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name=_('username'))
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, verbose_name=_('Email'))
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
        message='Телефонный номер должен состоят максимум из 15 цифр')
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Phone number'))
    firstname = models.CharField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(2)], max_length=50, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Firstname'))
    lastname = models.CharField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(2)], max_length=50, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Lastname'))
    patronymic = models.CharField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(2)], max_length=50, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Patronymic'))

    birth_day = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('Birthday'))
    org_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Organization name'))
    org_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Organization address')) 
    inn_id = models.CharField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(12)], max_length=12, unique=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('INN ID'))
    passport_s = models.CharField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(4)], max_length=4, unique=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Passport number'))
    passport_n = models.CharField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(8)], max_length=8, unique=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Passport series'))

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_('Online'))
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('Admin'))
    is_editor = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('Editor'))
    is_registrator = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('Registrator'))

    objects = AuthUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['lastname', 'firstname', 'patronymic', 'email', 'phone_number', 'org_name', 'org_address', 'birth_day', 'inn_id', 'passport_s', 'passport_n']

    def format_date(self, obj):
        return obj.date.strftime('%d.%m.%y')
    format_date.short_description = 'Дата'

    def get_full_name(self):
        return u'%s %s %s' % (self.firstname, self.patronymic, self.lastname)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return u'%s' % self.username

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

    @property
    def is_superuser(self):
        return self.is_admin

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        """
        Sends an email to this User.
        """
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])  


class OrgRequestManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, way_to_treat, email, 
                org_name, org_address, inn_id,
                employees, description, date):

        details = self.model(
            way_to_treat=way_to_treat,
            org_name=org_name,
            org_address=org_address,
            email=email,
            inn_id=inn_id,
            employees=employees,
            description=description,
            date=date)
        details.save()

        return details

class OrgRequest(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'OrgRequests'
        verbose_name = 'поле (организация)'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Заявления от организаций'

    way_to_treat = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=False, verbose_name=_('Way to treat'))
    org_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=False, verbose_name=_('Organization name'))
    org_address = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=False, verbose_name=_('Organization address'))
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
        message='Телефонный номер должен быть введён следующим образом: "+999999999". Разрешено до 15 символов.')
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Phone number'))
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, verbose_name=_('Email'))
    inn_id = models.CharField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(12)], max_length=12, unique=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('INN ID'))
    employees = models.CharField(max_length=999, unique=False, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Employees'))
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, unique=False, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Description'))
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=_('Date'))

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s - %s' % (self.way_to_treat, self.org_name)

    def get_full_name(self):
        return u'%s %s [%s]' % (self.way_to_treat, self.org_name, self.org_address, self.date)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return u'%s' % self.org_name
```

Форма:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
# from django.forms import ModelForm
# from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
# from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm
from .models import AuthUser
from .models import OrgRequest

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Логин', max_length=30, required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'text','id':'username','placeholder':'Логин'}))

    password = forms.CharField(label='Пароль', max_length=30, required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'password','id':'password','placeholder':'Пароль'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')


class OrgRequestForm(forms.Form):
    way_to_treat = forms.CharField(label='ФИО, имя или псевдоним', max_length=120,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'text','placeholder':'ФИО, имя или псевдоним и т.д.'}))

    org_name = forms.CharField(label='Организация', max_length=120,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'text','placeholder':'Наименование организации'}))

    org_address = forms.CharField(label='Организация', max_length=120,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'text','placeholder':'Адрес организации'}))

    email = forms.EmailField(label='Электронная почта', max_length=254, required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'email','placeholder':'example@example.ru'}))

    phone_number = forms.CharField(label='Телефонный номер', max_length=15, required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'text','placeholder':'8-XXX-XX-XX-XXX'}))

    inn_id = forms.CharField(label='ИНН', max_length=12, required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'text','placeholder':'ИНН организации'}))

    employees = forms.CharField(label='Сотрудники', max_length=50, required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'text','placeholder': 'Кол-во заинтересованных сотрудников'}))

    description = forms.CharField(label='Доп. информация', max_length=500, required=False,
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'text','placeholder':'Дополнительная информация (500 символов)'}))

    date = forms.CharField(label='Дата заполнения', max_length=10, required=True,
        widget=forms.DateInput(format=('%d.%m.%Y'), attrs={'class': 'input-group date','type':'date'}))

    class Meta:
        model = OrgRequest


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    lastname = forms.CharField(label='Фамилия', max_length=30, required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'text','placeholder': 'Фамилия'}))

    firstname = forms.CharField(label='Имя', max_length=30, required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'text','placeholder': 'Имя'}))

    patronymic = forms.CharField(label='Отчество', max_length=30, required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'text','placeholder': 'Отчество'}))

    username = forms.EmailField(label='Логин', max_length=254, required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'text','placeholder': 'Логин'}))

    email = forms.EmailField(label='Электронная почта', max_length=254, required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'email', 'placeholder': 'Электронная почта'}))

    org_name = forms.CharField(label='Наименование организации', max_length=30, required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'text','placeholder':'Наименование организации'}))

    org_address = forms.CharField(label='Адрес организации', max_length=30, required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'text','placeholder': 'Адрес организации'}))

    phone_number = forms.CharField(label='Номер телефона!', max_length=11, required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Номер телефона'}))

    birth_day = forms.CharField(label='Дата рождения', max_length=10, required=True,
        widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','type': 'date'}))

    inn_id = forms.CharField(label='ИНН', max_length=12, required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'text','placeholder': 'ИНН'}))

    passport_s = forms.CharField(label='Серия паспорта', max_length=4, required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'text','placeholder': 'Серия паспорта'}))

    passport_n = forms.CharField(label='Номер паспорта', max_length=8, required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'text','placeholder': 'Номер паспорта'}))

    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Пароль',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'password','placeholder': 'Пароль'}))

    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Пароль',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'password','placeholder': 'Пароль ещё раз'}))

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(SignUpForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = AuthUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'phone_number', 'lastname', 'firstname', 'patronymic', 'birth_day', 'inn_id', 'passport_s', 'passport_n')

        label = {
            'username': 'Логин',
            'password1': 'Пароль',
            'password2': 'Пароль (ещё раз)',
        }
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Т.к. ошибку выводит тот код, который нам не показан, то фиг его знает, почему он вызывается.

Comment: @jcommander, вы расширяете модель пользователя с помощью наследования `AbstractBaseUser`, но почему у вас в `AuthUserManager` нет функции `_create_user` ?

Comment: @AlTheOne, она обязательна? Просто, как я и говорил, он регистрирует в админке, но не в форме.

Comment: @jcommander, В тех статья, которые я читал - указывают эту функцию. Но это не значит, что это решит вашу проблему. В логах пишет какую-нибудь ошибку при регистрации с формы?

Comment: @AlTheOne, как можно отобразить ошибку?

Comment: @jcommander, чтобы не забивать вопрос комментариями создал чат: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83513/django----- дальнейшее обсуждение в нём

Answer (score 2):

Вообщем, вся у вас форме `SignUpForm`, а именно:

```
username = forms.EmailField(label='Логин', max_length=254, required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'text','placeholder': 'Логин'}))
```

Ваше поле логин указан как `EmailField`. От этого и ошибка. Исправьте на `CharField` этой ошибки не будет.